# What preposition is used with Weekend

Tags: word-choice

When is Pat going to call you?

I' am expecting him to call sometime ______ the weekend.

a)in
b)on
c)over

Answer (score 1):

In this case, none:

> I expect him to call sometime this weekend.

That said, **on** and **over** apply where one's weekends are concerned; and if you wish to be all cute (or all formal) about it, then "in the course of" might just do the trick. Not always, though.

> I'll get to it **on** the weekend.
>
> I'll be working on it **over** the weekend.

Or, upon @JEL's suggestion:

> I'll be working on it **during** the weekend.

Pronounced "DOO-ring" or "DEW-ring," depending on the neighborhood.

Another suggestion from Relentless JEL is:

> I'm expecting him to call sometime, come the weekend.

Comment: @JEL: It's too easy. Oh, okay, thanks, I'll make the edit.

Comment: I can't say I approve of posting an Answer to a question which is so obviously a duplicate. Not that I looked very closely at the original anyway, but I'd have thought answers there would make it clear ***on** the weekend* is still very much an *American* usage. The original question *title* also explicitly mentions American English - but this one doesn't, so there's even more reason to point out that in *British* English the standard alternative to ***over*** is ***at** the weekend*.

Comment: In Britain we do things *on Saturdays, and on Sundays* but never *on the week-end*. Always, *at, over,* or *during*.

Comment: @WS2: _At_, really?

Comment: I'm far happier with 'I'll see him at the weekend' than with 'I am expecting him to call sometime at the weekend'.

Comment: @JEL: Okay, another edit, just for you, credit and all.

Comment: @JEL: Duly noted.

Comment: In my part of England - Yorkshire - 'on the weekend' is used. It appears (as in I have done no research) that 'on' is used usually when speaking in general terms "He likes to go drinking on the weekend" while 'at' is used for more specific statements "I am visiting my parents at the weekend".

Comment: +1 to include other expressions that are not included in the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this question is from burlington book Michigan Proficiency exams (grammar session) and i must choose one.